# How to allow only few special characters in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to give permission to enter **@** and **&** with normal letters and numbers. But it isn't giving the results I expected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(str) == false) {
    alert('Your search string contains illegal characters.');
}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="str" id="str" />
<input type="button" name="btn" id="btn" value="btn"/>
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: [`/^[a-zA-Z0-9\- @&]+$/.test($('#str').val())`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/p28rmgn1/)

Comment: You didn't put much effort to fix the regex, do you?!

Comment: @ A.Wolff thing is I don't know much Regex

Comment: @pippilongstocking Could help you to understand it: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your `Regex` in your `jQuery` function as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    var ar =/^[ A-Za-z0-9-@&]*$/;
    if(ar.test('YourInputString') == false) {
    alert('Your search string contains illegal characters.');
}
  });
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpocx9cz/)

Comment: You forgot to add the hyphen back in